# Having both X and Y axes' Scales in Altair respond to a selection interval

Tags: altair, vega-lite

I'm bringing this question from Altair's github. (https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/2456) Is there a way to get the Scale on Y-axis in the bottom chart to respond to the selection brush? I'd like to be able to pan around the top chart with a selection and see the zoomed-in results in the bottom chart. If I uncomment the alt.Y, then both the X and Y axes show Years and it's messed up. Is there a way to pass just an X or Y value in the 'brush' maybe? Thank you very much!

```
brush = alt.selection_interval(init={'x':[1950, 1970], 'y':[1500000, 2500000]}, encodings=['x', 'y'])
base = alt.Chart().mark_line().encode(
    x=alt.X('Year:Q', title=None),
    y='Deaths:Q',
    color='Entity:N'
)
  
alt.vconcat(    
    base.add_selection(brush).encode().properties(height=150, width=150),
    base.encode(
        alt.X('Year:Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=brush)),
        #alt.Y('Deaths:Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=brush)) # (un)commenting this line makes it work/fail only along the x-axis    
    ).properties(
    height=500, width=500
),
    data='https://vega.github.io/vega-datasets/data/disasters.csv'
)
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see [Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289ABF1SMgAIkJ9XCiYkssg0FJ1JpuoYQYJzGxMe2AdxMACgAzGnUITBMAJgAGAEpfOEErTDhlExw2GllMCBMcsy8kJhTKRRUkGzRQBnVBNEqbAignCCkZeQBfJUwjWQgQtnUENABtUH8c5QDx0DYcRvUAgH1ZBgQmOHUKpAgl1fXN7ZAugF1zpRgoOVbMOZAcJyQEfdQJkFkXuEbXdxgKhBkqlGjk0upiEgGkpIYIGD9UKAAB7jAAsYgUAEZYrEzkoAJ7jADMsQUqNxXUuIGQ6gA1o0smCKnBZDdlDkyDUQCjESAwsllI0ABLDIFZfwnXr4nAIkAARwYth0Nh0pFOBK5-MEgvQAFkaCkICsZeoVgBxKGCOQVTDS2UKpV0Ko0NU9EA3K07Xk3WTsnTW3lPIyjdB-DwVLU6kAAYXxwl9232UpljWG7K+DTdsPhjTIlkJlJ6oD6tkGwxDHzCgnBXKDL1+bnDlLxGB9dweNPp6EZuWZrLY6c5vJ5oEjwtFcHFkpAtpT6AduSdqp+SmgUIRoAAXts2GgQlCgZSNbyx3qDWpjdtzZbrcn7YrFyqXSuQGuUlzt8s9we4Ef3WxPU1GgBUaWN41UCIbTtVN1HTKFTmbKlLBkQQ1V5FIyBZHVQA9YZQQTGUE17QsgA)
[image]
It filters the data of the 2nd chart using a filter transform on the brush param.

Comment: Yah, that's exactly what I wanted :) but could this be done in Python/Altair?